# using $location.path() for redirection in firebase

Tags: angularjs, redirect, firebase

I want to redirect to different page after successful submission of form in angularjs using firebase.
I am using push() for pushing data in database of firebase.Here is my controller implementation-

```
.controller('AddPostCtrl',['$scope','$location',function($scope,$location){


$scope.AddPost=function(event){
    var firebaseObj=new Firebase("https://boiling-inferno-5476.firebaseio.com/Article");
    event.preventDefault();
    var title=$scope.article.title;
    var post=$scope.article.post;
        firebaseObj.push({
        title:title,
        post:post
    },function(error){
        if(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else
        {
            $location.path('/welcome');
        }
    })

}
}])
```

On clicking submit button of form page should be redirected to 'welcome' page,but i have to click **twice** to do that.is there any error in my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $location.path('/welcome');
});
```

The `$location` service uses the `$digest` phase to start the route change. That's why you have to use the `$apply` function when the `$location` service is used outside of the scope life cycle. And that's why your second click applied the route changed upon the first click.

Comment: thanks it worked
can you explain the reason behind it why i have to do that??